# Derivative equal to original function

Tags: derivatives

How many different functions $f(x)$ exist such that $f'(x) = f(x)$?

The ones I know of right now are $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = ne^x$, for any real number $n$. What other functions satisfy this property?

Comment: Note that $(\ln f(x))'=1$ (if $f(x)\ne0$)

Comment: Your "first" example is just your second one with $n=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple Ordinary differential equation. And all solutions are of the form
$$f(x)=Ce^x$$
for some real constant $C$. Note that $f(x)=0$ as soon as you set $C=0$.

---

**proof.**
\begin{align}
f'(x)& =f(x), \forall x\\
f'(x)e^{-x}- f(x)e^{-x}&=0, \forall x\\
f'(x)e^{-x}+ f(x)(e^{-x})'&=0, \forall x\\
(f(x)e^{-x})'& =0, \forall x\\
f(x)e^{-x}&=C, \forall x\\
f(x)&=Ce^x, \forall x
\end{align}

Comment: An elegant proof.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Thanks. I love this method since we don't need to assume that $f(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: It is better to write $ \forall x\in \Bbb R $ before and $ \implies $ at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Write the equation as $\frac{dy}{dx} = y$.

Take the reciprocal of both sides, integrate and make $y$ the subject:

$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{y}$

$x = \ln y + C$

$x - C = \ln y$

$e^{x-C} = y$

$y = C_1 e^x$